# Referential Integrity in schema, cascading the renaming

Tags: mysql, schema

In phpMyAdmin, while renaming a column/table which is referenced by some foreign key, I get an error. I can not rename a column until I remove all its relations.

There should be facilitated integrity of schema, just like referential integrity i.e. cascading on delete and update column/table name.

User should be allowed to rename a column/table only if user has also permissions to the related tables/columns. Then, cascade this change throughout schema i.e. (foreign keys,triggers etc.)

I have tried to post above request on mysql here [Link](http://www.mysql.com/about/contact/) but get error `This form is invalid or has expired, please try again shortly`

Please guide me `Is this a good request` . No? then why? Yes? then where should I and how can i submit it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Referential integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity) is one, and is an attribute of the table data, but it is not an attribute of the table's schema. A table's schema shouldn't be changed in a cascading style, because it can break existing **working** code. A table's column is not used only in foreign keys, triggers, etc. It's used in scripts, maintenance plans, jobs, applications, dlls, even web pages etc. If you change an object's name you can create a mess, that's why it shouldn't be done automatically. This is something you want to control.

This is where [refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) tools can enter the scene. Eg for MS SQL Server there's Visual Studio db projects that can help here, but not by much. There may be tools that aid in refactoring the db objects and fix anything automatically, but they are not part of any standard db package.

Comment: Thanks @Marian. I could be more happy if had been told about mysql refactoring tool :)

Comment: @Sami: Sorry, mate. I'm not familiar with tools for MySQL. Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663/what-kind-of-database-refactoring-tools-are-there) on StackOverflow can help. I'm sure that our friend Rolando can help here, he's well into MySQL :-).